# python for loop in while loop but better

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I solved a python tutorial, but I definitely think my way is not the best.

can anyone recommend the better while loop solution or any other solution?

```
def solution(cryptogram):
    return decode(cryptogram)

def decode(str1):
    check = True
    list1 = list(str1)

    while check:
        check = False

        for i in range(len(list1)-1):

            if list1[i] == list1[i+1]:
                del list1[i+1]
                del list1[i]       
                check = True
                break
        
        if check == True:
            continue

        result = ''.join(list1)

        return result

print(solution('browoanoommnaon'))
```

this was the question

Brown, a geek developer who likes ciphers, has created a new password this time using duplicate characters.
For example, the ciphertext browoanoommnaon can be decrypted in the following order:

```
1. "browoanoommnaon"
2. "browoannaon"
3. "browoaaon"
4. "browoon"
5. "brown"
When an arbitrary string cryptogram is given as a parameter, 
complete the solution method to return the result of deleting 
consecutive duplicate characters.

Restrictions
A cryptogram is a string that is 1 or more and 1000 or less in length.
The cryptogram consists only of lowercase alphabetic characters.
I/O example
cryptogram result
browoanoommnaon brown
zyelleyz ""
I/O example explanation
I/O example #1
It's like an example of the problem.

I/O example #2
It can be decoded in the following order:

1. "zyelleyz"
2. "zyeeyz"
3. "zyyz"
4. "zz"
5. ""
```

Comment: The question is missing.

Comment: It looks like this is more suitable for [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce a bit code length.

```py
def solution(str1):
    list1 = list(str1)

    while True:
        check = False
        for i in range(len(list1) - 1):
            if list1[i] == list1[i + 1]:
                del list1[i + 1], list1[i]
                check = True
                break
        
        if check:
            continue
        else:
            return ''.join(list1)

print(solution('browoanoommnaon'))
```

Or you can also solve it recursively like

```py
def solution(str1):
    list1 = list(str1)

    for i in range(len(list1) - 1):
        if list1[i] == list1[i + 1]:
            del list1[i + 1], list1[i]
            return solution(''.join(list1))

    return ''.join(list1)

print(solution('browoanoommnaon'))
```

Anyway, your approach was good.

Hope I helped